# How to update table in SQL Server with Entity Framework?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

My table name is `StcDocItems`:

```
id      partRef   DocTypeRef  itemRef
--------------------------------------
3850    366          12        NULL
3851    367          63        3850
```

I'd like to update `partRef` to (in this case 366) `partRef` of the record that its `itemRef` is equal to its `Id` and its `DocTypeRef` is 63.

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure what you're trying to do.... **assuming** you want to update the **whole table**, you could try something like this:

- load the whole table into memory as a `List<StcDocItems>`
- loop over each item and see if it has a matching entry - if so, update it

So this would be the code to do this:

```
public class StcDocItems
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PartRef { get; set; }
    public int DocRefType { get; set; }
    public int? ItemRef { get; set; }
}

using(YourDbContext ctx = new YourDbContext())
{
    // get all rows from table
    List<StcDocItems> allItems = ctx.StcDocItems.ToList();

    // iterate over items
    foreach(StcDocItems item in allItems)
    {
        // do we find a row which has "ItemRef = Id" and "DocTypeRef = 63" ?
        StcDocItems updateToItem = allItems.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ItemRef = item.Id && i.DocTypeRef = 63);

        // if we found an item
        if(updateToItem != null)
        {
            // set the partRef to new item's partRef
            item.PartRef = i.PartRef;
        }
    }

    // save any changes back to database table
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, How to do this in TSQL

Answer (score 1):

```
Update StcDocItems set partRef =366 where itemRef=id and DocTypeRef =63
```